# Golang encapsulate a function

Tags: go, dll, shared-libraries

I have a function in go that I want to provide it to others(in other Go programs on unix servers). However, I don't want them to know the implementation so I can not just give them the source code. I've check out the c-shared buildmode but it seems troublesome because of all the conversions between C types and Go. I wonder if there are simpler ways like

```
lib := load(somelib)
res := lib.somefunc(args)
```

Comment: Go has not the concept of compiled libraries per-se. Implementing it as a service - and providing some end points such as REST, NATS, gRPC, etc - seems to be more convenient.

Comment: The sample code you posted is doable with plugins. Check out the [`plugin`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) package.

Comment: @icza I have been advised against using `plugin` package because it might go away. Does that still stands?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian I haven't heard anything about plugins going away. Can you give a (reliable) source?

Comment: Thanks! @icza Is it possible to reverse engineer a go plugin

Comment: @Ethan To some extent, yes. To reconstruct the exact same Go source, not. If you worry that much about your code, the only option is not to share your code but run a server and let clients connect to it.

Comment: @icza My mistake, sorry; yet this comment by Ian Lance Taylor suggests that it might hange. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/nKY2rDRe9sE

Comment: @KavehShahbazian The current plugin (package) interface is very minimalistic. Even if they introduce changes, I doubt they will be backward-incompatible changes; it's too easy to "keep" this minimalistic interface. Also there is the Go 1 compatibility promise.

Comment: But bear in mind that plugins are only supported on Linux.

Comment: @Adrian And macOS since Go 1.10: _"Currently plugins are only supported on Linux and macOS. "_